# Suggest books on Combinatorial Graph Theory

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am going to start self-studying ***Combinatorial Graph Theory***. Kindly suggest books or study materials available online.

I have been told that it is basically application of linear algebra, mainly the eigenvalue/eigenvector things on *Graph Theory.* So, any book or material focusing on that particular aspect broadly will be very helpful.

Till date I have studied only linear algebra and little to no introductory graph theory and I have zero knowledge of combinatorics (in case that is also required). So, kindly suggest something that can be handled by a beginner like me.

Thank  you very much.

Comment: "I have been told that it is basically application of linear algebra , mainly the eigenvalue/eigenvector things on Graph Theory." That's usually called algebraic graph theory.

Comment: @quid : May be . I don't know. Someone told me that. I know nothing. Please help me explore.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you actually want to do. Why do you intend to study "Combinatorial Graph Theory" and what does this mean to you?

Comment: @quid : Why do I want to study that? How about because I don't have anything else to do to pass the time? It means nothing more than timepass to me. OK?

Comment: The point of my question may have been lost: do you want to study "application of linear algebra , mainly the eigenvalue/eigenvector things on Graph Theory" or do you want to study "Combinatorial Graph Theory" and believe this is the former?

Comment: @quid : Clearly you did  not read  my full post . Like I said , someone  told me those two are quite the same . Now I don't know. If you cannot suggest books/study materials  so I can see the similarities or differences or whatever there is , don't ask any more of these questions. It's scary.

Comment: For "application of linear algebra , mainly the eigenvalue/eigenvector things on Graph Theory." see Biggs, Norman (1993), Algebraic Graph Theory, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press

Comment: @quid : And for the "combinatorial graph theory " thing ? Don't know any?

Comment: I am sorry but as I tried to convey I do not understand what is meant by "combinatorial graph theory."

Comment: @quid : Do you mean that is not even a thing ? Actually I also found nothing when I googled it so may be, we just leave it.The Normann Briggs book you said , I cannot find any link to download that.

Comment: It could mean counting graphs of certain types like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_enumeration but I do not know much about that. For the download: I read it long ago from a library I do not know about an online version. (I read it as  books or (study materials available online) not  (books or study materials) available online).

Comment: @quid : Thanks anyway . I just got the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

[Combinatorics and Graph Theory by Harris, Hirst and Mossinghoff](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387797106) covers a wide variety of topics in combinatorics and graph theory. It includes results and problems that cross subdisciplines, emphasizing relationships between different areas of mathematics.